# QAxObject -- not creating excel in right format

Tags: qt, qaxobject

I am working with `QAxObject` and able to open existing file & read different sheets & cells.

But when i am creating a new excel file using `QAxObject`. It is creating the `test_1.xls` file.
But when i open this file it gives me error. I am using `ms-excel-2007` .

Code :---

```
   QAxWidget excel_1("Excel.Application");
   excel_1.setProperty("Visible", false);

   QAxObject * workbooks_1 = excel_1.querySubObject("WorkBooks");

   workbooks_1->dynamicCall("Add");
   QAxObject * workbook_1 = excel_1.querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook");
   QAxObject * worksheets = workbook_1->querySubObject("WorkSheets");

   excel_1.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", 0);
   workbook_1->dynamicCall("SaveAs (const QString&)", QString("D:\\Temp\\test_1.xls"));
   workbook_1->dynamicCall("Close (Boolean)", false);
   excel_1.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", 1);
   excel_1.dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
```

`error message` when i try to open this file :-----

```
The file you are trying to open is diffrent format than xls. 
Verify that file is corrupted or not do you want to open this file or not
```

Please suggest what i am missing to create `.xls` file in correct format ?

Answer (score 2):

OK,I solved this problem. Because I install Office2007,
       the "Save" function will save the file in 2007 format, but I save it to "*.xls", some format can not be recognized correctly.

so the solution is, use "SaveAs" to save excel to 2003 format.

[How to set excel column format though Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141582/how-to-set-excel-column-format-though-qt)

```
QList<QVariant> lstParam;
lstParam.append("D:\\Temp\\test_1.xls");
lstParam.append(-4143);
lstParam.append("");
lstParam.append("");
lstParam.append(false);
lstParam.append(false);
lstParam.append(1);
lstParam.append(2);
lstParam.append(false);
lstParam.append(false);
lstParam.append(false);
lstParam.append(false);

workbook_1->dynamicCall("SaveAs(QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant, QVariant)", lstParam);
```